# QGIS Connect to MSSQL (Esri Enterprise DB)

Tags: qgis, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I have a QGIS setup for deploying map data to the field using QField where it grabs the data from a Esri file geodatabase. I recently moved the data into a Esri Enterprise DB in MSSQL and would like to change my QGIS to point to those data layers. I can connect to the database through an MSSQL connection in the Browser but none of the tables seem to be spatially aware even though they list a geometry type and number of entities. Is the Enterprise DB just not compatible?

Comment: Esri doesn't support anything but native geometry in SQL Server any more, so the tables have to be using native geometry. If the tables are versioned there may be difficulty accessing the versioned geometry, but you seem to have a different, albeit unclear, issue.

Comment: I am trying to display and query the data in QGIS, no editing. From what I can find QGIS supports Esri datasets in file and enterprise geodatabases and I can add the tables they just have no geometry. As for native geometry QGIS should support that too as far as I can tell.

Comment: It should just work; whatever your issue, it seems more QGIS-SQL Server than QGIS-Esri.

Comment: I thought it might have something to do with it being an Enterprise DB with an Esri SDE; I am also baffled.